# Multiple http requests by same js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, xmlhttprequest, multiple-instances

i have a problem with my file js that call multiple http requests.
I have a button that call the function VisualizzaReport that is in my file visualizzaReport.js

Here is the function VisualizzaReport(select is the ID of the user)

```
    function visualizzaReport(select){
        reportUtente(select)
        loadPianificazione(select)
    }
```

Here the function reportUtente(select)

```
    function reportUtente(select) {
        var url = "../loadReportUtenteServlet?";
        url += "type=perso_atti&value=" + select.value;
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = handlerForReportUtente;
        xmlhttp.open("GET", url);
        xmlhttp.send("");

    }
```

Here the function loadPianificazione(select)

```
    function loadPianificazione(select) {
        var url = "../loadPianificazione2Servlet?";
        url += "type=pianificazioni&value=" + select.value;
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = handlerForPianificazioneUtente;
        xmlhttp.open("GET", url);
        xmlhttp.send("");
    }
```

my problem is that the function reportUtente is launched but has not effect because it seems that it is substitute by loadPianificazione function.
How can i call loadPianificazione only when reportUtente has finished his execution?

Answer (score 0):

In your case I suggest you use either **jQuery** or **AngularJs** for this purposes.

**jQuery** example:

```
$.get('url1.com', function(){
    $.get('url2.com');
})
```

You will request **url2.com** only when first request has finished.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be using a single, global `xmlhttp` variable.

Then you call two functions which do things with it. The second one will overwrite `xmlhttp.onreadystatechange` before the first request has finished so the second function you put there will be called for each request.

Don't do that. Create a new instance of `XMLHttpRequest` for each request, and keep it in a local scope so that it doesn't interfere with other instances.

```
function reportUtente(select) {
    var url = "../loadReportUtenteServlet?";
    url += "type=perso_atti&value=" + select.value;

    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); // New instance here

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = handlerForReportUtente;
    xmlhttp.open("GET", url);
    xmlhttp.send("");

}
```

You haven't shared `handlerForReportUtente` but it should look something like:

```
function handlerForReportUtente() {
    alert(this.responseText); // Use `this` to get the right XHR object
}
```